# Show that a set defined on a arc segment is closed

Tags: measure-theory

A arch measure defined by $B(r,R,\eta,\theta)$ defined by two angels $0<\eta<\theta<2\pi$ and 2 radians $R>r>0$. The arc segment consists of 2 vectors $x\in \Bbb R^2$, which has the lenght between $r$ and $R$. Define a angle measure $\omega:\Bbb R^2\setminus \{0\}$ by $\omega(x)\in [0,2\pi)$. The angle measure is uniqly defined by 
$$
\frac{x_1}{\|x\|_2}=\cos(x) \qquad \frac{x_2}{\|x\|_2}=\sin(x)
$$
where $\|x\|_2=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$. You can use (without proof) that $\omega$ is continuous $\Bbb R^2\setminus\{(x_1,0)\mid x_1\ge 0 \}$. Now define 
$$
B(r,R,\eta,\theta)=\{x_\in\Bbb R^2\mid\omega(x)\in [\eta,\theta],\|x\|_2\in [r,R]\} \qquad (1)
$$
where it is also assumed that $\emptyset\in B$.

**Definition:** The paving $\Bbb D$  is the empty set $\emptyset$ or a set given by (1) for $0\le\theta\le\eta<2\pi$ and $R\ge r>0$

> Show that the set $B(r,R,\eta,\theta)$ is closed and that $\Bbb D \in \Bbb B_2$

My guess is that I have to show that the product set given by $\|x\|\times \omega$ is closed. But I am rally lost. Any hints or help is very much appriciated.

Comment: Why do you think this is a question related to elementary set theory?

Comment: I want to show that a **set** is closed.

Comment: I changed ti to measure theory. It is from a measure theory class.

Comment: Just because something includes a **set** doesn't mean it has anything to do with set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be the function defined from $\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{R}_+ \times \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined by 
$$ f(x) = (\|x\|,\omega(x)).$$

Then $f$ is a continuous function; the only thing that really needs to be checked is that $\omega$ is continuous on the set $\mathbb{R}^2 - \mathbb{R}_+ \times \{0\}$ and can be proved by giving an explicit formula for $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$, knowing $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$. I let you show that.

Then, the set you are interested in is $f^{-1}([r,R] \times [\eta,\theta])$. So you can conclude using that a function is continuous if and only if the inverse image of any closed set is closed.

I don't understand the second part of your question; I think some notations are missing.

Comment: $\Bbb B\otimes\Bbb B \Bbb = B_2$ is the product borel algebra. Does that help?

Comment: what is meant by "the paving of arc segments"?

Comment: It is my own translation from Danish. But I think maybe just *arc* is the correct word. This is what I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)

Comment: I stil don't understand where $\mathbb{D}$ lives. Is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, how is it defined?

Comment: Or $\Bbb D$ is pavings of the set $B$

Comment: You have not defined the set $B$.

Comment: That is: sets of subsets of $B$

Comment: Edit your question defining what is $B$ relatively to $B(r,R,\eta,\theta)$ and what is $\mathbb{D}$. Then I will be able to answer you.

Comment: I added a definition

Comment: This still does not make sense. "the set of elements in a set B" is $B$ itself and you have not defined it. What I understand is that $\mathbb{D}$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $B(r,R,\eta,\theta)$. But it makes no sense to ask if $\mathbb{D}$ is measurable since it is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Try to understand what you really want to prove...

Comment: Okay. I see why you are confused. I wrote it wrong. What i meant is that the set $\Bbb D$ is a collection of sets, which is either a empty set of a set on $0\le\theta\le \eta$  and $R\ge r>0$

Comment: If $\mathbb{D}$ is a collection of sets, it has no meaning to ask if it is measurable. If it is a particular set of the form $B(r,R,\eta,\theta)$, then it is obvious that it is measurable since it is closed.

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra is also a collection of sets. And surly  you can find examples of some sigma algebra generated on a set $X$, such that the $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of the Borel algebra. So another way to ask is may to say that $\Bbb D$ is a subset of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B$

Comment: This is not what you have written. If $\mathbb{D}$ is a set of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you want to show that it is INCLUDED in the $\sigma$-algebra, then it is obvious since all elements in $\mathbb{D}$ are closed and closed sets are measurable.